# Looping a whole python function until true

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm new to python and I want to archive a function as below where a input of a user gets checked with the arithmetic operators against the case of the random typed number being true to the statement `number < 100` and when not being looped by the elif function.

So I want to check the first if statement but if that is not true it should go to the elif statement and then be checked by the if statement again until it fits the criteria.

```
def unit(number):
    if number < 100:
        a = round(((number/10)-(number//10))*10)
        return a
    elif number => 100:
        number/10

userInput = int(input("Your number please: \n"))
print(unit(userInput))
```

SOLVED!

I could solve the problem by doing the following changes:

```
userInput = int(input("Your number please: \n"))
def unit(number):
    if number < 100:
        a = round(((number/10)-(number//10))*10)
        return a
    elif number >= 100:
        b = (number/10)
        return unit(b)

print(unit(userInput))
```

Comment: When you say "looping a whole function" do you mean an actual function such as ``unit`` or a *statement* such as ``for``, ``if`` or ``while``?

Comment: You can use **while**

Comment: Both in a way, I want to check the first if statement but if that is not true it should go to the elif statement and then be checked by the if statement again. I don't know if that means that the whole unit function has to be "called" again. @MisterMiyagi

Comment: Note: In your code, line 5, the order of the equal sign and the greater than sign needs to be swapped: => should be >=. In line 6, put a return statement: return number / 10.

Comment: Thanks for the swapped sign hint! :) @GustavRasmussen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use recursion

```
def unit(number):
    if number < 100:
        a = round(((number/10)-(number//10))*10)
        return a
    elif number => 100:
        return unit(number/10)

userInput = int(input("Your number please: \n"))
print(unit(userInput))
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me an error: 
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: This actually helped me in the end! Thanks! I didn't know that you could return to the function (unit) itself with a new value (number).